# Vectorizing Numpy 3D and 2D array operation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, dot-product

I'm trying to create `K MxN matrices` in Python, stored in a `(M,N,K)` `numpy` array, `C`, from two matrices, `A` and `B`, with shapes `(K, M)` and `(K,N)` respectively. The first matrix is computed as `C0 = a0.T x b0`, where `a0` is the first row of `A` and `b1` is the first row of `B`, the second matrix as `C1 = a1.T x b0` and so on.

Right now I'm using a for loop to compute the matrices.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random((10,800))
B = np.random.random((10,500))
C = np.zeros((800,500,10))
for k in range(10):
    C[:,:,k] = A[k,:][:,None] @ B[k,:][None,:]
```

Since the operations are independent, I was wondering if there was some pythonic way to avoid the for loop. Perhaps I can vectorize the code, but I fail to see how it could be done.

Comment: @ handles batches, but the batch dimension `k` has to be at the front.  Aim for a (k,m,n) and transpose after.

Comment: @hpaulj Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [235]: A = np.random.random((10,800)) 
     ...: B = np.random.random((10,500)) 
     ...: C = np.zeros((800,500,10)) 
     ...: for k in range(10): 
     ...:     C[:,:,k] = A[k,:][:,None] @ B[k,:][None,:] 
     ...:                                                                            
In [236]: C.shape                                                                    
Out[236]: (800, 500, 10)
```

Batched matrix product, followed by transpose

```
In [237]: np.allclose((A[:,:,None]@B[:,None,:]).transpose(1,2,0), C)                 
Out[237]: True
```

But since the matrix product axis is size 1, and there's no other summation, broadcasted multiply is just as good:

```
In [238]: np.allclose((A[:,:,None]*B[:,None,:]).transpose(1,2,0), C)                 
Out[238]: True
```

Execution time is about the same